# Web server directory structure with additional volume for media (in Amazon EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, mount, symlink

I'm re-building my server (LAMP) structure. I have now only one root volume that includes all data. Now i'm adding (EBS volume) for userdata like media etc. so i can just backup that volume and not whole server. So my questions are:

- is it better way to use symlinks to point from www folder to mounted EBS volume or should i mount the volume straight under public www folder?
- is it good practice to move my MYSQL database files into that external volume too? (and this case mount the volume to non public folder)
- i want to automatically mount that volume when starting the instance so can there be some kind of timing issues like MYSQL can't access to it's data files if the EBS volume is mounted after MYSQL instance has already started?
- How can i backup the volume reliably while server is running with amazon's own tools or should i use rsync to create the backup to other volume?
- Drupal is used as main web application in this server

I have been working as an developer over 15 years and i know server side well too. Have searched for good articles etc related to these stuff, but found nothing exact.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Hi, your question could use some more detail on your own research, so that a) we can see that you made a valid effort to answer your own questions and b) for us to answer on a level that is appropriate for your pre-existing knowledge.

Comment: @FelixFrank edited my question..

Comment: Well, `/etc/fstab` is where you'd put the auto-mounting. Symlinks would be cleaner in general.